# Google App Engine "Multiline" and JavaScript array problem

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

How do I convert HTML textarea (multiline) to support db.StringProperty() (without the multiline)?

I have try `string.replace("\n", "<br>")` but the problem is when I insert this to javascript array it give me problem.

My code as following:

```
class Anything(db.Model):
 Str_A = db.StringProperty()
...

anything = Anything.all()

template_values = { 'anything ': anything }
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'main.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

In the Javascript

```
var Str_A = [];
{% for a in anything %}
 Str_A.push("{{ anything.Str_A }}");  /* This line problem */
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [db.TextProperty()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#TextProperty) which supports multi-line text by default, or [db.StringProperty(multiline=True)](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#StringProperty) if you need to search or sort on the `Str_A` property (db.TextProperty is not indexed).